# Возможно ли сделать обводку текста QLabel?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5

Как сделать обводку всего текста используя `QLabel`?

```
class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)    

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(50)

        background = QtGui.QImage("balloons.jpg").scaled(900, 900)

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QtGui.QBrush(background))

        self.setPalette(palette)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label 2", alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255,255,255,20%); color: #FFFFFF;")
        label.setFont(font)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эффект тени `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui                       
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsDropShadowEffect


class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)    

        background = QtGui.QImage("background.png").scaled(900, 900)      # balloons.jpg

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QtGui.QBrush(background))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label 2", alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
#        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 20%); color: #FFFFFF;")
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 20); margin: 50px;")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(50)
        label.setFont(font)

        shadow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self,
            blurRadius=14.0,                   
            color=QtGui.QColor("#f00"),
            offset=QtCore.QPointF(0.0, 0.0)  
        )
        label.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(layout)    


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Window2()
    window.resize(900, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Используя QLabel и Python - насколько я могу судить никак. Оно просто не предназначено для этого.
Но Вашу задачу можно решить используя QGraphicsScene куда можно добавить и картинку и QGraphicsSimpleTextItem; последний поддерживает обводку.